# Python how to handle split when delimiter not present?

Tags: python, syntax

I have the following python code:

```
def split_arg(argv):
    buildDescriptor = argv[1]
    buildfile, target = buildDescriptor.split("#")

    return buildfile, target
```

It expects a string (`argv[1]`) of the form `buildfile#target` and splits them into two variables of the same name. So a string like "*my-buildfile#some-target*" will get broken into *my-buildfile* and *some-target* respectively.

Sometimes though, there won't be "#" and target; sometimes you'll just have "*my-buildfile*", in which case I just want *target* to be "" (empty).

How do I modify this function so that it will handle instances where "#" doesn't exist and it returns buildfile with an empty target?

Currently, if I pass just the buildfile, it throws an error:

```
buildfile, target = buildDescriptor.split("#")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use duck typing, try to do what you want and catch exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but what is duck typing?

Comment: duck typing is one of the programming techniques most suited for Python programs, just google for "python duck typing".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, put the result of the split in a list:

```
split_build_descriptor = buildDescriptor.split("#")
```

Then check how many elements it has:

```
if len(split_build_descriptor) == 1:
    buildfile = split_build_descriptor[0]
    target = ''
elif len(split_build_descriptor) == 2:
    buildfile, target = split_build_descriptor
else:
    pass  # handle error; there's two #s
```

Answer (score 22):

I'd use the obvious approach:

```
    buildfile, target = buildDescriptor.split("#") if \
                        "#" in buildDescriptor else \
                        (buildDescriptor, "")
```

Note that this will also throw an Exception when there is more than one "#" in buildDescriptor (which is generally a GOOD thing!)

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> buildfile, _, target = "hello#world".partition("#")
>>> buildfile, target
('hello', 'world')
>>> buildfile, _, target = "hello".partition("#")
>>> buildfile, target
('hello', '')
```

This uses [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition()):

> `str.partition(sep)`
>
> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

Comment: +1, .partition() seems really elegant here (except for the dummy var), but it might behave strange (unnoticed) when there is more than one "#".

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in Python 3:

```
input_string = 'this is a test'
delimiter = '#'

slots = input_string.split(delimiter)
if slots[0] == input_string:
  print('no %s found' % delimiter)
else:
  print('%s found right after \"%s\"' % (delimiter, slots[0]))
```